# Tpmfs /run 100% used

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, vps

I have a VPS with Nginx for a wordpress blog and I have a problem I don't know for what reason.

Whenever `tmpfs 99M 20M 79M 21% / run` gets 100% of used my database drops and I need to reboot the server. I'm starting with servers and I don't know what is causing it.

Is there a configuration error?

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            465M     0  465M   0% /dev
tmpfs            99M   20M   79M  21% /run
/dev/sda1        19G   12G  6.6G  64% /
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           493M     0  493M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/0
```

Dist: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: Check fstab and incraise the space or use hdd

Comment: What the hell is in you /run when you're at 100%? Apart for a bit of systemd garbage, I only have sockets and PID files in there so 99M of usage seems pretty high so it might be useful to understand what's happening